# docker-compose does not launch

Tags: docker, cassandra, docker-compose, cqlsh

I'm trying to use docker-compose to launch 2 images 
 - Apache Cassandra running as a server
 - Another similar container, but running the sql interpreter

I'm pretty new to docker, this is what I've tried so far:

Here's my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  cassandra-srv:
    image: cassandra:latest
    ports:
     - "7000:7000"
     - "7001:7001"
     - "9042:9042"
     - "7199:7199"
     - "9160:9160"
    container_name: cassandra-srv
  cqlsh:
    build: cassandra-build
    image: cassandra:mycqlsh
    links:
     - cassandra-srv
    container_name: cassandra-client
    depends_on:
     - cassandra-srv
    entrypoint:  /usr/local/bin/wait-for-it.sh cassandra-srv:9042 && cqlsh
```

The idea here is that I have defined two services. I've opened up more ports than needed, both to the local machine and the other docker image. The server should start, and the client during startup will use a little utility script to wait for the server to fully startup, and will then jump into the interactive shell. In order to do that the base cassandra image is tweaked via this Dockerfile:

```
FROM cassandra
MAINTAINER jonesn@uk.ibm.com
ENV container docker
WORKDIR /tmp

ADD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh /usr/local/bin
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wait-for-it.sh
```

However whilst I can
 * Launch the cassandra image just fine
 * Launch that same image but straight into cqlsh by running the command direct on the docker invocation
 * Build the refined docker image

What I cannot do is simply run "docker-compose run cqlsh" having expected this to build the client image, launch the server, wait, and jump into the shell.

I'm sure lack of docker-compose knowledge is the cause, anyone care to provide a few hints for this newbie? ;-)

Thanks
Nigel.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why run cqlsh in another container?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own newbie questions

```
docker-compose up
```

is enough to launch both the client and the server given the above definitions, and additionally the entrypoint line needed to be changed to

```
entrypoint:  /usr/local/bin/wait-for-it.sh -t 300 cassandra-srv:9042 -- cqlsh cassandra-srv 9042
```

to extend the timeout, and also for the wrapper script itself to launch the sql interpreter

In fact this doesn't work either, since the cqlsh container will exit as no terminal is attached. Using the docker-compose "run" command seems to be a better option

```
docker-compose run cqlsh cqlsh localhost 9042
```